# Decay Modes - Stepper Motor related Query

Tags: dc-motor, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I'm trying to understand something fundamental about Decay Modes.It is widely accepted on the internet that a slow decay mode shorts the Back-EMF of the motor and in essence stops the motor instantaneously. Hence the torque generated is higher when slow decay mode is used in comparison with Fast Decay Mode. I have a few queries regarding this

1. When slow decay mode is used, the motor is shorted to ground through the Rds of the of lower MOSFETs, this doesn't imply that the voltage across the coil has to become zero, a high enough current can flow to maintain a high Back-EMF.
2. When the Back-EMF is zero the current through the coil is still present, doesn't the coil current dictate the torque generated? Why does the Back-EMF have precedence over the coil current when it comes to the torque.
   Please help me clear any misconception I have regarding this

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that current and voltage are *always* tied unless there is an impedance in between. That impedance could be (and often just is) the wiring but usually we think at components as 'directly connected'. In the same way 'instantaneously' doesn't exist, otherwise mechanically the motor would rip itself from the bearing from the inertia and torque.

Decay modes in stepper are mostly related to how current is regulated in the winding. Do not confuse steppers with brushed DC: a supplied DC motor runs, a supplied stepper motor just *holds position* with some torque. You need to commutate the phases to do this.

Also back-EMF is way less relevant in stepper unless at high speeds (it's used for stall detection, for example, but it doesn't work at slow speed).

Since current regulation in the winding is done following the current ramp of the winding decay modes changes indirectly the control profile: the driver can only make the current rise (with the time constant of the windings) or let the current decay (either shorting or leaving open the bridge). The resulting current ripple is actually torque ripple (holding torque or running torque depending on the mechanical alignment).

The issue arises especially with microstepping when the current controlled is different from the current one: it can only rise at one speed but can decay at *two* different speeds. It gets even more complex since the drive can use fast decay for one part of the cycle and slow decay for the rest of the cycle. Like for PWM the net result is any decay speed in between (this is called mixed decay).

Each controller does it in its own way: I used the DRV8885 and there are more than 4 pages in the datasheet explaining pros and cons of each decay modes.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, so am I right in saying that in a stepper motor slow decay mode will generate larger ripple torques than fast decay mode?

Comment: no, it's the opposite, at least in constant off time control (one of the most common AFAIK, along with pure PWM). Citing the datasheet: "Slow decay exhibits the least current ripple of the decay modes for a given tOFF . However on decreasing current steps, slow decay will take a long time to settle to the new ITRIP level because the current decreases very slowly.".
ALSO: it really only matters when you are microstepping or really concerned about ripple, for most applications it's nitpicking